# Android - cannot find symbol method getSystemService(String)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Im new in java/android, 
im trying make fragment activity and implement adapter into my fragment 'tab2' but getting eror code in line(adapter.java) :

inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

im already trying to fix. but still cant resolve this. So, what is wrong in my code? 
this my full code adapter.java :`

```js
package com.yoga1215051164.fragment2.adapter;

/**
 * Created by Yatogami on 24/05/2017.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.yoga1215051164.fragment2.R;
import com.yoga1215051164.fragment2.data.Data;
import com.yoga1215051164.fragment2.tab2;
import java.util.List;


public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private tab2 activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Data> items;

    public Adapter(tab2 activity, List<Data> items) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return items.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        TextView id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id);
        TextView nama = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nama);
        TextView alamat = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alamat);

        Data data = items.get(position);

        id.setText(data.getId());
        nama.setText(data.getNama());
        alamat.setText(data.getAlamat());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

and this  code fragment tab2.java :

```js
package com.yoga1215051164.fragment2;

/**
 * Created by Yatogami on 25/05/2017.
 */


import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.yoga1215051164.fragment2.adapter.Adapter;
import com.yoga1215051164.fragment2.app.AppController;
import com.yoga1215051164.fragment2.data.Data;
import com.yoga1215051164.fragment2.util.Server;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class tab2 extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener{

    FloatingActionButton fab;
    ListView list;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;
    List<Data> itemList = new ArrayList<Data>();
    Adapter adapter;
    int success;
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    View dialogView;
    EditText txt_id, txt_nama, txt_alamat;
    String id, nama, alamat;

    private static final String TAG = tab2.class.getSimpleName();

    private static String url_select   = Server.URL + "select.php";
    private static String url_insert   = Server.URL + "insert.php";
    private static String url_edit       = Server.URL + "edit.php";
    private static String url_update   = Server.URL + "update.php";
    private static String url_delete   = Server.URL + "delete.php";

    public static final String TAG_ID       = "id";
    public static final String TAG_NAMA     = "nama";
    public static final String TAG_ALAMAT   = "alamat";
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabmenu2,container,false);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            fab     = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fab_add);
            swipe   = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
            list    = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);

            adapter = new Adapter(tab2.this, itemList);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

            swipe.setOnRefreshListener(this);

            swipe.post(new Runnable() {
                           @Override
                           public void run() {
                               swipe.setRefreshing(true);
                               itemList.clear();
                               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                               callVolley();
                           }
                       }
            );

            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    DialogForm("", "", "", "SIMPAN");
                }
            });

            list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                               final int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    final String idx = itemList.get(position).getId();

                    final CharSequence[] dialogitem = {"Edit", "Delete"};
                    dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(tab2.this);
                    dialog.setCancelable(true);
                    dialog.setItems(dialogitem, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            switch (which) {
                                case 0:
                                    edit(idx);
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    delete(idx);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        return v;
        }

        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            itemList.clear();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            callVolley();
        }

    private void kosong(){
        txt_id.setText(null);
        txt_nama.setText(null);
        txt_alamat.setText(null);
    }


    private void DialogForm(String idx, String namax, String alamatx, String button) {
        dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(tab2.this);
        inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.form_biodata, null);
        dialog.setView(dialogView);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        dialog.setTitle("Form Biodata");

        txt_id      = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txt_id);
        txt_nama    = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txt_nama);
        txt_alamat  = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txt_alamat);

        if (!idx.isEmpty()){
            txt_id.setText(idx);
            txt_nama.setText(namax);
            txt_alamat.setText(alamatx);
        } else {
            kosong();
        }

        dialog.setPositiveButton(button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                id      = txt_id.getText().toString();
                nama    = txt_nama.getText().toString();
                alamat  = txt_alamat.getText().toString();

                simpan_update();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.setNegativeButton("BATAL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                kosong();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }
    
    private void callVolley(){
        itemList.clear();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        swipe.setRefreshing(true);
        
        JsonArrayRequest jArr = new JsonArrayRequest(url_select, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        Data item = new Data();

                        item.setId(obj.getString(TAG_ID));
                        item.setNama(obj.getString(TAG_NAMA));
                        item.setAlamat(obj.getString(TAG_ALAMAT));
                        
                        itemList.add(item);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                swipe.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                swipe.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

  
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jArr);
    }

  
    private void simpan_update() {
        String url;
        if (id.isEmpty()){
            url = url_insert;
        } else {
            url = url_update;
        }

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    success = jObj.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                   
                    if (success == 1) {
                        Log.d("Add/update", jObj.toString());

                        callVolley();
                        kosong();

                        Toast.makeText(tab2.this, jObj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(tab2.this, jObj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(tab2.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                if (id.isEmpty()){
                    params.put("nama", nama);
                    params.put("alamat", alamat);
                } else {
                    params.put("id", id);
                    params.put("nama", nama);
                    params.put("alamat", alamat);
                }

                return params;
            }

        };

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_json_obj);
    }
    
    private void edit(final String idx){
        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_edit, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    success = jObj.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    
                    if (success == 1) {
                        Log.d("get edit data", jObj.toString());
                        String idx      = jObj.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String namax    = jObj.getString(TAG_NAMA);
                        String alamatx  = jObj.getString(TAG_ALAMAT);

                        DialogForm(idx, namax, alamatx, "UPDATE");

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(tab2.this, jObj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(tab2.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
               
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("id", idx);

                return params;
            }

        };

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_json_obj);
    }
    
    private void delete(final String idx){
        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_delete, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    success = jObj.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

               
                    if (success == 1) {
                        Log.d("delete", jObj.toString());

                        callVolley();

                        Toast.makeText(tab2.this, jObj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(tab2.this, jObj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                  
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(tab2.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
               
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("id", idx);

                return params;
            }

        };

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_json_obj);
    }

}
```

Thankyou

Comment: Why aren't you using an ArrayAdapter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to pass the context to your adapter so your adapter should look like this

```
private Context context;
public Adapter(Context context, List<Data> items) {
        this.context=context
        this.items = items;
    }
```

and use this context like this

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

and send context from your fragment like this

```
Adapter adapter=new Adapter(getActivity(),listItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Fragment` does not extend `Context` that is why you cannot call `getSystemService`. Instead of passing the fragment instance, pass the context from the fragment's host activity. It is advisable to instantiate the Adapter in `Fragment.onAttach()` since you are sure that the context is valid. And also, use

```
LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

if you want to get an instance of the inflater.